# Distortion in react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am facing video distortion in react-native-video(not everytime), I am attaching the snap below

[image]

Attaching code snippet for video component

```
                <Video
                  controls={false}
                  onLoad={onLoad}
                  onBuffer={onBuffer}
                  onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
                  onProgress={onProgress}
                  onEnd={onEnd}
                  paused={!play}
                  ref={videoPlayer}
                  resizeMode={screenType}
                  source={{
                    uri: getSourceHls(),
                  }}
                  style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    backgroundColor: Colors.background,
                  }}
                  volume={10}
                />
```

Could anyone guide me what am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had similar problem with react-native-video (4.4.5), I too have been trying to get some solution. In my case it was not happening always with all videos, it was happening with certain mobile device. After upgrading version from 4.4.5 to 5.1.1 I saw improvement, I am currently monitoring. I will request you to try upgrade react-native-video to latest (5.1.1) which should give you some benefit.